# Scala troubles getting data in a single Json line

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, spark-streaming

I am using Scala spark streaming , and I need to push my results to a kafka topic. I am using     `.selectExpr("to_json(struct(Column1,Column2,Column3,Column4))as value")`     .

And I get the result:

```
{"Column1":"Value_Column1","Column4":"Value_Column4"}
{"Column1":"Value_Column1","Column2":"Value_Column2"}
{"Column1":"Value_Column1","Column3":"Value_COlumn3"}
```

How should I change the .selectExpr or what are the steps I need to take to get an output like this :

```
{"Column1":"Value_Column1","Column2":"Value_Column2","Column3":"Value_Column3","Column4":"Value_Column4"}
```

Thank you all in advance!

Comment: Where does the value `"Column2":"Value_Column2" ` comes from ?

Comment: @koiralo it comes from Spark dataframe ,where columns have been merged together by a common column - timestamp

Comment: but you don't have that value in the input dataframe

Comment: @koiralo I have, every value shows up and works, the problem I currently have is that it parses it into 3 seperate json strings, which would be 3 different rows in a database, but I'd like to get it all in 1 json string, and I think it's the .selectExpr which I don't know how to correctly write to put it all in 1 json string. Sorry if I can't answer the question as you'd like, this is my first step into Big data,spark streaming,kafka.

Comment: would be nice to have a more sample input data and few more expected output data

Comment: The input data : |-- Column1: string (nullable = true)
 |-- Column2: string (nullable = true)
 |-- Column3: null (nullable = true)
 |-- Column4: timestamp (nullable = false)

Comment: Your expression produces one line of output data for each line in the input dataset. Is that what you want? Or are you looking for a way to group lines together?

Comment: @werner group the output lines together so that kafka topic would output  `{"Column1":"Value_Column1","Column2":"Value_Column2","Column3":"Value_Column3","Column4":"Value_Column4"} `

Comment: Please add an example of the input table and the expected output data to the question (not only the schemas)